# Returning the minimum value of array with the index of the minimum value

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections

How could I implement in java a function that returns the minimum value of an integer array and the index of the minimum value?
in other words to return pairs value, first value is the minimum value, the second value is the index of that minimum value.

What I know that there's a built in function in java to find the min value, but I also need to return the index of that minimum value in the array.

array is type integer.

Comment: Hi , no already checked that before posting .

Comment: It's not clear why the question linked by ATP is not a valid answer for your question, because it explains how to return more than one piece of information at a time from a Java method. Can you clarify why that question is different to yours?

Comment: Let's see what you have tried.

Comment: Hey, why don't you show us some of your code, instead of expecting us to do your homework. Read here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the array, updating the current minimum index as you go.

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
int minIdx = 0; //maybe handle empty array
for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
   if(arr[i] < arr[minIdx]) minIdx = i;
}
System.out.println("Min index: " + minIdx + ", min value: " + arr[minIdx]);
```

If you want to return the result from a method, you can either use an array or a value object.

```
public int[] getMin(final int[] arr){
   if(arr.length == 0) return null; //empty
   int minIdx = 0;
   for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
      if(arr[i] < arr[minIdx]) minIdx = i;
   }
   return new int[]{minIdx, arr[minIdx]};//first element is index, second is value
}
```

Comment: I want to return two elements (pairs) by a function , I mean pairs the min value and its index. I'm confused of what you attached because it doesn't return pair.

Comment: @TonyVany I've updated my answer.

Comment: so it returns an array of two elements? thanks alot

Comment: @TonyVany No problem.

Comment: @iota we are dealing with an Object Oriented language. 
Why did you suggested create an array of two elements instead of a class?

Comment: @SergeantCortez I was merely providing options: "[...] you can either use an array or a value object." I just provided implementation of the former method.

Comment: @iota so it returns an array of two elements? also I pressed on the left side of your comment (on the arrows) in order to accept your answer

Comment: @TonyVany Yes, it does.

Comment: @iota in my previous thread  I will do the same for you

Comment: @TonyVany *pressing on the left side of comments* does not accept answers. Please consider to see [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and also [ASK]

Comment: @iota Hi , for assigning that you answered my question as I promised you now I did it(I've permission) ; second question may you please modify your code in how I can in the return of the method to choose which object to assign? I mean for instance lets assume I'm on the other function and I called your method so [Minvalue index] =getMin(given array) ; I want to save the returned objects of getMin into MinValue variable and into index variable how can I do that which your method return pair values?

Comment: @iota really appreciated if you could modify your code and thanks for your help. once again lets assume I have on the other function two variables called MinValue and Index variables, I want to store the returned pair of getMin method into those two variables correspondingly , this means to do something like this  [MinValue index] =getMin(given array) which means that first pair stores into MinValue variable  which stores the returned minimum value and second pair is stored in the index which it's the index of the minimum value.... could you please help me on this?

Comment: @TonyVany `int[] result = getMin(arr); int minIdx = result[0], minVal = result[1];`